# How to use Argo CD to pass environment variables to deploy in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, development-environment, argocd

We are using argo cd and kubernetes.

And I want to use environmental variables in the yaml file.

For example,

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: guestbook-ui
  annotations:
spec:
  ports:
    - port: $PORT
      targetPort: $TARGET_PORT
  selector:
    app: guestbook-ui
```

I want to set the value of the environmental variable (PORT and TARGET_PORT) when deploying it to Argo CD.

What should I do?

Comment: One of the motives for using gitops tools like ArgoCD is that the code running in your infrastructure is identical to what you store in your git repository. In another words you avoid transforming and strings to acutal values like the traditional CI/CD process.

Comment: @Benjamin Is there any document related to that?

Comment: @Benjamin On AWS EKS you can have IAM resource manifests that refer to the AWS account number. When you have several accounts onto which you want to deploy a complete environment defined in git, then hardcoding the account number would not work. It would be nice to be able to refer to `$AWS_ACCOUNT` in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend converting your raw YAML to a Helm chart and templating the relevant fields.

Argo CD has an [example Helm app](https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps/tree/master/helm-guestbook) with a service similar to yours.

You could define a service like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: guestbook-ui
  annotations:
spec:
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
  selector:
    app: guestbook-ui
```

And then define your port and targetPort parameters in Argo CD.

Comment: define how? where should I set this?

Comment: @KorjavinIvan when you deploy a Helm chart in Argo CD, you define an [Application manifest](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/operator-manual/application.yaml). That manifest provides several ways to set a parameter value. One is by writing raw YAML into the `spec.source.helm.values` field as a string. Another is by setting parameters by name in `spec.source.helm.parameters`.